# Behaviour of inout within Swift operators

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I'm playing around with some functional programming and defining operators in Swift and noticed this quirk which confused me.
If I have a generic function which takes in an inout operator and passes it to a function:

```
func operatorEquivalent <A> (input: inout A, function: (inout A) -> Void )
{
    function(&input)
}
```

then I call it like so:

```
operatorEquivalent(&myStruct, myInoutFunction)
```

**with** the ampersand.

But if the the generic function is translated to an operator like so:

```
infix operator >!

func >! <A> (input: inout A, function: (inout A) -> Void )
{
    function(&input)
}
```

then I call this operator like so:

```
myStruct >! myInoutFunction
```

**without** the ampersand.

Could anyone explain why this is so and / or point to any documentation on this detail?
Curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&`-prefixed expression is called a [in-out expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/expressions/#In-Out-Expression). As the Swift language reference says, this is only used when you pass `inout` parameters to [*function call expressions*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/expressions/#Function-Call-Expression).

> An in-out expression marks a variable that’s being passed as an in-out argument to a function call expression.

The expression `myStruct >! myInoutFunction` is not a function call expression. It is an [infix expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/expressions#Infix-Expressions), which doesn't require special syntax for passing `inout` parameters.

I suspect one of the reasons why it is this way comes down to aesthetics. With compound assignment operators, the code looks more C-like with such a design. Compound assignment operators have their first parameter declared as `inout`. For example, see [`AdditiveArithmetic.+=`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/+=(_:_:)-5g9ip):

```
static func += (lhs: inout Self, rhs: Self)
```

Arguably, the code would look rather weird if you had to add an extra `&` and write `&foo += x` instead of `foo += x`. The idea of adding `&` in the first place is to indicate that the call might change the argument. One could argue that with operators like `+=`, the intent is already clear, even without `&`.

Comment: "I suspect one of the reasons why it is this way comes down to aesthetics." - I suspect that is the *only* reason.